# Why does JQuery require a global "window" object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jsdom

I'm using `jsdom` together with `jquery` to scrape static web content in a Node.js application.

`jsdom` converts an HTML string to a DOM tree, including a `window` property. I found that I had to assign the DOM's `window` property to `global.window`, otherwise JQuery errors (saying that a global window object is required). Why is this required?

```
// Create DOM from HTML
const JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
const jsDom = new JSDOM('<html>...</html>')

// Set up JQuery
const { window } = jsDom;
const { document } = window;
global.window = window;
const $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');

// Scrape content
const tbl = $(document)
  .find('#table-id')
  .find('tr').each(function() {
    // Do something with $(this).html()
  })
```

Also, I have often seen this: `const $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');` Why is `global.jQuery` required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery expects to be running in a browser. In a browser `window` is present in the global space, and jQuery makes use of it for some of its features. In Node.js, your code is running in a scope created for the file that contains it. Even if you don't think of it as a *module*, Node.js does not make the distinction all of your `const` (and `let`) declarations at the top level of your file declare variables that are scoped to your file. So `const { window } = jsDom;` is not putting `window` in the global space, and it is not accessible to jQuery.

You have two choices when you run jQuery in Node:

1. Do what you are doing: first expose `window` into the global space, then load jQuery. This works fine.
2. You can instead do this:

   ```
   const JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
   const jsDom = new JSDOM('<html>...</html>');

   const { window } = jsDom;
   const { document } = window;
   const $ = global.jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
   ```

You are asking also about `const $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`. In my experience, most libraries that depend on jQuery (like jQuery plugins for instance) refer to it as `jQuery`. They run in an IIFE like this:

```
(function ($) { // Inside the IIFE, jQuery is bound to $.


}(jQuery)); // jQuery is grabbed from the global space as jQuery.
```

So you want `jQuery` in the global space to support libraries that depend on it.

Comment: Thank you - do you know offhand what features in jQuery require a global window property and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
const jsDom = new JSDOM('<html>...</html>');
const $ = global.jQuery = (require('jquery'))(jsDom.window);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using JS module with `import $ from 'jquery'`, the easiest solution is probably to dynamically import the modules in the test AFTER you set the `global.window` and `global.document`:

```
// MyFooUsejq.js
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class MyFooUsejq {
    #$myDiv;
    constructor(selector) {
        this.#$myDiv = $(selector);
    }

    get innerHtml() {
        return this.#$myDiv.html();
    }
}
```

```
// MyFooUsejq.test.js
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

test('use jquery', async () => {
    const jsdom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><div id="foo">hello</div></body></html>`);
    global.window = jsdom.window;

    const { default: MyFooUsejq } = await import('Pupil/Common/MyFooUsejq');
    const foo = new MyFooUsejq('#foo');
    expect(foo.innerHtml).toBe('hello');
});
```