# How to set global window for jQuery in a vitest test (jQuery requires a window with a document)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vitest, webpack-encore

Probably less important: Setup is done with webpack Encore which generates a webpack config file, we use `yarn` as a package manager, so `vitest` is installed with `yarn`.

- jQuery version 3.6.4
- vitest version 1.2.2

Here is a simplified problem:

```
// vitest.config.js
import path from 'path';

export default {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/packages')
        }
    }
};
```

```
// MyFooUsejq.js
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class MyFooUsejq {
    #$myDiv;
    constructor(selector) {
        this.#$myDiv = $(selector);
    }

    get innerHtml() {
        return this.#$myDiv.html();
    }
}
```

```
// MyFooUsejq.test.js
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import MyFooUsejq from 'Common/MyFooUsejq'; // Common is an alias configured with webpack.
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

test('use jquery', () => {
    const jsdom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><div id="foo">hello</div></body></html>`);
    global.window = jsdom.window;
    global.document = jsdom.window.document;
    const foo = new MyFooUsejq('#foo');
    expect(foo.innerHtml).toBe('hello');
});
```

Running `yarn vitest --config=vitest.config.js MyFooUsejq.test.js` gives error:

> Error: jQuery requires a window with a document

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52589859/5233188 setting a global window object should work for jQuery to detect it.

How can I keep `import $ from 'jquery';` and set a window for jQuery in `MyFooUsejq`?

Comment: You need the global `window` to exist before you import jQuery. So `MyFooUsejq` should check for the `window` global, and if it finds it, import jQuery with a dynamic import something like `import('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js').then((module) => window.$ = module)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey But there are quiet a few modules like `MyFooUsejq` that import jQuery. Although your suggestion might work, it "breaks" the module way, the effort seems to high change this for tests... But thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) advised, jQuery needs to be loaded AFTER setting the global `window`, but instead of using dynamic imports in all modules that `import` jQuery, I added a dynamic import inside the test for `Common/MyFooUsejq`. But I also think I set `global.window` and `global.document` wrong.

Working test:

```
// MyFooUsejq.test.js
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

test('use jquery', async () => {
    const jsdom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><div id="foo">hello</div></body></html>`);
    global.window = jsdom.window;

    const { default: MyFooUsejq } = await import('Pupil/Common/MyFooUsejq');
    const foo = new MyFooUsejq('#foo');
    expect(foo.innerHtml).toBe('hello');
});
```